# How to list pages from an author?

Tags: pages, author

I want to show the pages (not the posts) of an author on his author page.

Is it a listing possible ?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Seems very much possible, yes. Have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

And add the username to the array

```
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_pages  
  <?php $args = array(
        'sort_order' => 'asc',
        'sort_column' => 'post_title',
        'hierarchical' => 1,
        'exclude' => '',
        'include' => '',
        'meta_key' => '',
        'meta_value' => '',
        'authors' => '',
        'child_of' => 0,
        'parent' => -1,
        'exclude_tree' => '',
        'number' => '',
        'offset' => 0,
        'post_type' => 'page',
        'post_status' => 'publish'
    ); 
    $pages = get_pages($args); 
    ?>
```